# How to copy a MySQL database excluding customer data?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I have a database (MySQL, AWS RDS). This is a production database that has customer information including names, emails, bank account information. Some of it is encrypted, some of it is not.

We want to setup an environment that can be regularly used for automated testing. We want the database for the test environment to be the same as production except we want to replace customer data.

We want to do this in a way where the customer data never leaves the production environment. We don’t mind creating an “intermediate” environment that may initially contain some customer data but then gets removed. From the intermediate environment, we’d transfer the cleaned database to the testing environment.

Appreciate the guidance since I’m way out of my depth here

Comment: Manually. MySQL doesn't have any clue which of your bits of data are sensitive and which are not. You'll have to write scripts to handle this, and maintain them on an ongoing basis. Alternatively, write database seeders that build a set of test data from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy / automated solution to do this that I am aware of. You need to replicate your data to a different system and have that replication service scrub your data for you. A few options come to mind:

- You could write a batch processor that dumps the DB down to disk, loads it into a secondary server (staging/scrubbing environment), and then run a series of cleanup scripts. Then you can again dump the data down.
- You could write a database [trigger](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/) that fires on the events you care about and maintains a staging table of sanitized data.
- You could write a test data generator that users the patterns of your production data to generate fake data in a testing table. [There](https://dev.to/iainfreestone/20-resources-for-generating-fake-and-mock-data-55g1) [are](https://www.mockaroo.com/) [many](https://generatedata.com/) [tools](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/) [that](https://mimesis.name/en/master/) can help with this, both open source and commercial.

Personally, I lean towards the last option because it's the safest and can be used in many places, like on a local dev machine, CI/CD system, shared staging environment, etc. I do believe there is a strong case for sending a copy of a subset of production data to canary systems as part of a rollout strategy, though. Effectively testing your release with live data before wiring it to your live database.